# Jumping around of the dockerfile/docker-compose context

Tags: docker, docker-compose

My current projects structure looks something like that:

```
/home/some/project
│   .credentials_dev
│   .credentials_prod
│   ca.cer
│   docker-compose.yml
│   Dockerfile
│   init.sql
│   nginx_dev.conf
│   nginx_prod.conf
│
├───src
└───users
```

Compose makes four containers, two of them are dev & prod version of application, who uses appropriate prod & dev files. As you can see, following structure root is little overloaded, so i'd like to move all the deployment staff into the separate directory to make the following:

```
/home/some/project
├───deployment
│       .credentials_dev
│       .credentials_prod
│       ca.cer
│       docker-compose.yml
│       Dockerfile
│       init.sql
│       nginx_dev.conf
│       nginx_prod.conf
│
├───src
└───users
```

The idea is to receieve in the result following structure on the docker host:

```
host
├───dev
│   ├───src
│   └───users
├───prod
│   ├───src
│   └───users
└───project
    ├───deployment
    │       .credentials_dev
    │       .credentials_prod
    │       ca.cer
    │       docker-compose.yml
    │       Dockerfile
    │       init.sql
    │       nginx_dev.conf
    │       nginx_prod.conf
    │
    ├───src
    └───users
```

and two containers app_dev and app_prod, which volumes are appropriate mounted into folders /host/dev and /host/prod.

I tried multiple solutions found here, but all of them in different variations returned the following errors:

```
ERROR: Service 'app_dev' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder264200969/ca.cer: no such file or directory
```

```
ERROR: Service 'app_dev' failed to build: COPY failed: Forbidden path outside the build context: ../ca.cer ()
```

Error is always appears while docker-compose is trying to build an image, on that string:

```
COPY deployment/ca.cer /code/
```

Please tell me how to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

The Deployment folder is outside of the build context. Docker will pass all the files **inside** the deployment file as the build context. However the deployment folder itself is outside of it.

Change your copy statement to be instead :

```
COPY ./ca.cer /code/
```

Since in the image you are already in that folder.